# How to refresh my ListView?

Tags: android, listview, swiperefreshlayout

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private ListView listView;
    private FeedListAdapter listAdapter;
    private List<FeedItem> feedItems;
    private String URL_FEED = "http://myozawoo.esy.es/data.php";
    private String URL_FEED2 = "http://api.androidhive.info/feed/feed.json";

    private SwipeRefreshLayout swipeContainer;

//     String page = getIntent().getExtras().getString("page");
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 0);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

//        String page = getIntent().getExtras().getString("page");

        swipeContainer = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipeContainer);
        swipeContainer.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                parseJsonFeed();

            }
        });


        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        feedItems = new ArrayList<FeedItem>();

        listAdapter = new FeedListAdapter(this, feedItems);
        listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

        // These two lines not needed,
        // just to get the look of facebook (changing background color & hiding the icon)
//        getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#3b5998")));
//        getActionBar().setIcon(
//                new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent)));

        // We first check for cached request
//        Cache cache = AppController.getInstance().getRequestQueue().getCache();

        // Page One
        String page = getIntent().getExtras().getString("page");
        if(page.equals("1")) {
            Cache cache = AppController.getInstance().getRequestQueue().getCache();
            Entry entry = cache.get(URL_FEED);
            if (entry != null) {
                // fetch the data from cache
                try {
                    String data = new String(entry.data, "UTF-8");
                    try {
                        parseJsonFeed(new JSONObject(data));
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            } else {
                // making fresh volley request and getting json
                JsonObjectRequest jsonReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Method.GET,
                        URL_FEED, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Response: " + response.toString());
                        if (response != null) {
                            parseJsonFeed(response);
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                    }
                });

                // Adding request to volley request queue
                AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonReq);
            }
        }

        //Page Two

        else if (page.equals("2")) {
            Cache cache = AppController.getInstance().getRequestQueue().getCache();
            Entry entry = cache.get(URL_FEED2);
            if (entry != null) {
                // fetch the data from cache
                try {
                    String data = new String(entry.data, "UTF-8");
                    try {
                        parseJsonFeed(new JSONObject(data));
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            } else {
                // making fresh volley request and getting json
                JsonObjectRequest jsonReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Method.GET,
                        URL_FEED2, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Response: " + response.toString());
                        if (response != null) {
                            parseJsonFeed(response);
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                    }
                });

                // Adding request to volley request queue
                AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonReq);
            }
        }

        // Other Four Pages
        else {
            Cache cache = AppController.getInstance().getRequestQueue().getCache();
                Entry entry = cache.get(URL_FEED);
                if (entry != null) {
                    // fetch the data from cache
                    try {
                        String data = new String(entry.data, "UTF-8");
                        try {
                            parseJsonFeed(new JSONObject(data));
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                } else {
                    // making fresh volley request and getting json
                    JsonObjectRequest jsonReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Method.GET,
                            URL_FEED, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                            VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Response: " + response.toString());
                            if (response != null) {
                                parseJsonFeed(response);
                            }
                        }
                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                        }
                    });

                    // Adding request to volley request queue
                    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonReq);
                }

        }

        swipeContainer.setColorSchemeColors(android.R.color.holo_blue_bright,
                android.R.color.holo_green_light,
                android.R.color.holo_orange_light,
                android.R.color.holo_red_light);

    }





    /**
     * Parsing json reponse and passing the data to feed view list adapter
     * */
    public void parseJsonFeed(JSONObject response) {
        try {
//            String page = getIntent().getExtras().getString("page");
//            if (page.equals("1"))
            JSONArray feedArray = response.getJSONArray("feed");

            for (int i = 0; i < feedArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject feedObj = (JSONObject) feedArray.get(i);

                final FeedItem item = new FeedItem();
                item.setId(feedObj.getInt("id"));
                item.setName(feedObj.getString("name"));

                // Image might be null sometimes
                String image = feedObj.isNull("image") ? null : feedObj
                        .getString("image");
                item.setImge(image);
                item.setStatus(feedObj.getString("status"));
                item.setProfilePic(feedObj.getString("profilePic"));
                item.setTimeStamp(feedObj.getString("timeStamp"));

                // url might be null sometimes
                String feedUrl = feedObj.isNull("url") ? null : feedObj
                        .getString("url");
                item.setUrl(feedUrl);

                feedItems.add(item);
            }

            // notify data changes to list adapater
            listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        swipeContainer.setRefreshing(false);
    }


}
```

I want to refresh my ListView. Now, I can't refresh. I don't know how to refresh. How to do in onRefresh(){}. I can't call parseJSON() to onRefresh(){}. Please tell me someone. Thanks you very much! :-)

Answer (score 1):

In your page change call, use adapter to clear the items in ListView

```
listAdapter.clear();
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

If you are using a custom adapter that extends Android ArrayAdapter, you may not find .clear() because private class varies depending on implementation. For instance, .update()

Anyway, try make changes here and see if it works.

```
swipeContainer.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                // ---- RIGHT HERE THIS LINE     
                listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
```

Comment: I don't know what you mean. :-(

Comment: Please write sample code. I hope! Sorry for my poor english.

Answer (score 0):

You have used adaper on list view as

```
listAdapter = new FeedListAdapter(this, feedItems);
    listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
```

Now after updating its value you can call

> listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

You are looking for method to refresh list view data then its method available in adapter notifyDataSetChanged();

In hour pareseJsonFeed update with

```
it...



    /**
     * Parsing json reponse and passing the data to feed view list adapter
     * */
    public void parseJsonFeed(JSONObject response) {
        try {
//            String page = getIntent().getExtras().getString("page");
//            if (page.equals("1"))
            JSONArray feedArray = response.getJSONArray("feed");

            for (int i = 0; i < feedArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject feedObj = (JSONObject) feedArray.get(i);

                final FeedItem item = new FeedItem();
                item.setId(feedObj.getInt("id"));
                item.setName(feedObj.getString("name"));

                // Image might be null sometimes
                String image = feedObj.isNull("image") ? null : feedObj
                        .getString("image");
                item.setImge(image);
                item.setStatus(feedObj.getString("status"));
                item.setProfilePic(feedObj.getString("profilePic"));
                item.setTimeStamp(feedObj.getString("timeStamp"));

                // url might be null sometimes
                String feedUrl = feedObj.isNull("url") ? null : feedObj
                        .getString("url");
                item.setUrl(feedUrl);

                feedItems.add(item);
            }
            listAdapter.clear();
            listAdapter.addAll(feedItems);
            // notify data changes to list adapater
            listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        swipeContainer.setRefreshing(false);
    }


}
```

Comment: Did you mean?swipeContainer.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {

                listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

Comment: listAdapter.clear() and listAdapter.addAll(feedItems) can't write. When I write, I face red underline. :-(

Answer (score -1):

Try to invalidate your cached data this is when you're calling again to the server. It is the last call in `AppController.getInstance().getRequestQueue().getCache().invalidate(key,boolean)`